# grails remoteFunction update attribute

Tags: grails

The Grails documentation for the remoteFunction update attribute states:

update (optional) - Either a Map containing the elements to update for 'success' or 'failure' states, or a string with the element id to update, in which case failure events would be ignored

I'm a little confused why the indicate a Map and not a List here, is this wrong?   I imagine I want my remote action to return a Map, where the keys match the name of the list elements specified in the update attribute??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `update`, if you want to replace a part of the current page, which is identified by the (html)-id in the `update` tag. E.g.:

```
<div id="resultOfAJAX"></div>

<g:remoteFunction update="resultOfAJAX" [..] />
```

However this is not useful, if the AJAX call fails. That is why you can define which element is to be updated in the failure case:

```
<div id="resultOfAJAX"></div>
<div id="someErrorField"></div>

<g:remoteFunction update="[success: 'resultOfAJAX', failure: 'someErrorField']" [..] />
```

I am not sure, whether this clarifies your question regarding `update`, but maybe it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks crudolf.  I don't think I can currently do what I want, and think the documentation on this is slightly wrong, i.e. it should probably state, "a Map containing the elements to update for 'success' AND/or 'failure' states".  I.e. I read it as I could update multiple elements, for the success case.  E.g. User changes a select box, and multiple parts of the page get updated.  I was hoping I could return a map, where each key of the map, matches an ID specified in the 'update'.  I think this would be a good feature to have, and also the ability to update not just a div, but a form element.